# pandas read_excel how to skip rows with some specific text

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

i wanted to skip some rows starting with some specific text.

**Code:**

```
pandasDF = pd.read_excel("/Users/user1/Documents/filename.xls", sheet_name='Rates',header=1, comment='Note:', usecols=columns_list)
print(pandasDF)
```

Output:

```
0             01-01-2001  1.002500  1.601591  ...        NaN      NaN       NaN
1             02-01-2001  0.978400  1.608285  ...        NaN      NaN       NaN
2             03-01-2001  0.962800  1.606327  ...        NaN      NaN       NaN
3             04-01-2001  0.956900  1.591041  ...        NaN      NaN       NaN
4             05-01-2001  0.911300  1.567882  ...        NaN      NaN       NaN
5           Average rate  0.906352  1.544086  ...        NaN      NaN       NaN
6             06-01-2001  0.927400  1.571944  ...        NaN      NaN       NaN
7             07-01-2001  0.958600  1.558775  ...        NaN      NaN       NaN
8             08-01-2001  0.926600  1.546576  ...        NaN      NaN       NaN
9             09-01-2001  0.889100  1.549333  ...        NaN      NaN       NaN
10            10-01-2001  0.882500  1.525312  ...        NaN      NaN       NaN
11            11-01-2001  0.853910  1.512577  ...        NaN      NaN       NaN
12          Average rate  0.906352  1.544086  ...        NaN      NaN       NaN
```

I wanted to remove the rows starting with "Average rate". is there any attributes support that? or we need to iterate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simpliest is filter after create `DataFrame` by boolean mask with inverted condition by `~` and [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
pandasDF = pandasDF[~pandasDF['col'].str.startswith('Average rate')]
```

Or if need filter by values:

```
pandasDF = pandasDF[~pandasDF['col'].eq('Average rate')]
```